# Could Stack Overflow host JavaScript instead of using Google CDN?

Tags: support

I am a miserable Chinese programmer who uses Stack Overflow *almost* every day.
Things are never easy for Chinese programmers. Regardless of the language obstruction, we have to go though the [GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) to visit and cooperate with coders in the real world.

I hate GFW, and every one with conscience hates it. But Google's IP addresses, due to their bad relationship with the Chinese government, are all blocked by GFW. Including its public CDN for JavaScript such as `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` which Stack Overflow is using.

And I beg you people in charge of this site to change this `jQuery` for self-hosting or using other CDNs. Or at least for Chinese IPs. It's not Stack Overflow's fault nor Google's. Those who do evil should and will be punished. F**K GFW and God bless Stack Overflow.